# Question about how GCP resources communicate

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've got a few people I know who operate under the assumption that ***all*** GCP resources communicate over Google's internal network, even if something is configured to talk to an instance's public IP address (VM, SQL, etc). This seems possible through some complicated NAT management, but I'm not sure it's true.

For example, a web server is set up in one project to use a MySQL database that lives in another project. Without setting up VPC peering, we set the website to use the public IP of the MySQL database, since the private IP isn't available without peering. At this point, is the web server communicating with the MySQL database over the internet? Does this traffic leave Google's network at any point?

I've been unable to find docs that answer this question, but I could be searching the wrong terms. If someone could provide docs that would be very helpful.

Please let me know if I should clarify further.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a document that can answer your questions:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#protecting_services_on_machines_with_external_ip_addresses

To answer your question about the traffic leaving Google's network: It does not leave the network unless you imply it to  (meaning if you the customer configures it to)

The webserver communicates with the MySQL DB over the internet with the external IP, however, you can setup VPC tunnels and firewall rules to limit access.

Comment: I would like to add:

Resources within a VPC network can communicate with one another by using internal (private) IPv4 addresses, subject to applicable network firewall rules. For more information, see communication within the network.

Instances with internal IP addresses can communicate with Google APIs and services. For more information, see Private access options for services.

all answer are in this document:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc

I also recommend you read this thoroughly:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#communications_and_access